# React.js route exact path is not wokring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have problem with routing React.js.
I want to make URL like `http://localhost:3000/auth/login` but I don't know why it's not working.

Here's my code.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./../scss/main.scss";

import Home from "./pages/Home.jsx";
import Users from "./pages/Users.jsx";
import Login from "./pages/auth/Login.jsx";

render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route exact path="/auth/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

I create menu and I clicked it and other links are works fine but only the /auth/login URL is not working.
But if I change that URL to /login and change it in menu url it works. So multi directory(?) like /auth/login, /auth/example is not wokring.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How about if you remove all the exact props and reverse the order of the routes in your switch? I think that should work fine

Comment: @AshkanPourghasem You mean like this?  ```<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,``` . Still not working with exact props and without exact props.

Comment: The "multi directory" works fine with react router. you can even put "foo/bar/thing/etc" it will works. Are you sure you haven't made any typo in your routes or in your menu ? can you post the menu code please ?

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else. https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-matsumoto-gb2ho?fontsize=14

Comment: multi directory works in react router, there is no issue. Can you check whether any typo is there in the url when you are entering

Comment: you can try out it here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic. Also kindly create a working sample one with reproducible issue you can use codesandbox for it. So it will be helpful to solve the issue

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved with exact props and change the a tag to Link to tag. And it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this method. Thanks for the helps in comments.

The problem is from jsx file. At first I use a tag to route it but it should be `<Link to='/something/something'>EXAMPLE</Link>` like this.

And with this method. I can use exact path props. Actually, I confuse right now but now I know I should search about what is the difference with Link to and a tag.

And this is my fixed jsx code

```
class User extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navigation">
        <div className="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/auth/login">Login</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/auth/res">RES</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A related problem. Might helps someone else.

Mine works only if root (`/`) is `exact`, but not others:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeIndexPage} />
    <Route path="/role" component={RoleIndexPage} />
    <Route path="/user" component={UserIndexPage} />
  </Switch>
```

Imports are like this:

```
    import HomeIndexPage from './features/000.home/IndexPage';
    import RoleIndexPage from './features/100.role/IndexPage';
    import UserIndexPage from './features/101.user/IndexPage';
```